# Sum the odd digits in an integer

Tags: python, function, loops, sum

Below is my attempt when adding the odd digits of an integer:

```
def sumOdd(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if n % 2 == 0:  # if n is odd
            n -= 1
    print(sum(range(1, n, 2)) + n)  # The range(1,n,2) starts at 1 and counts by twos until it reaches n


sumOdd(123)  # 4
```

Any tips?

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly _what_ your problem is?

Comment: so your max `odd` number is only `9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two solutions, one is cast it to string, another is directly handle it as integer.

```
def sumOdd(n):
    n = str(n)
    sumn = 0
    for i in n:
        i = int(i)
        if i % 2 == 1:  # if n is odd
            sumn+=i
    return sumn

print(sumOdd(132495)) # 4388797504


def sumOdd_(n):
    n = abs(n)
    sumn = 0
    while n>0:
        digit = n%10
        n = n//10
        if digit %2 ==1:
            sumn+=digit
    return sumn

myn = 132495
assert sumOdd_(myn)==sumOdd(myn)
```

Or else, you could use pythonic way of using `divmod` in Python. And do note that generally div and mode runs faster than casting to str.

```
def sumOdd_2(n):
    sumn=0
    while n:
        # "pop" the rightmost digit
        n, digit = divmod(n, 10)
        if digit %2 ==1:
            sumn+=digit
    return sumn
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

#### Code:

```
def sum_odd_digits(number):
    return sum(int(d) for d in str(number) if d in '13579')
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(sum_odd_digits(123))
print(sum_odd_digits(133))
```

#### Results:

```
4
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

Preprocessing of data:

```
data=123456789

real_data=list(map(int,str(data)))
```

operation on processed data:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda x:x%2,real_data)))
```

or

```
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(filter(lambda x:x%2,real_data))))
```

output:

```
25
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>
def check_odd(a):
    if a % 2 == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def extract_last_digit(a):
    return a % 10

def remove_last_digit(a):
    return a // 10
 
x = input('Type an integer: ')

n = int(x)      

if n < 0:       # the integer may be negative (alternatively use n = abs(int(x)) in previous line)
    n = -1*n

sum_odd_n = 0

while n != 0:   
    if check_odd(n) == True:
        sum_odd_n += extract_last_digit(n)
    n = remove_last_digit(n)

print('The sum of the odd digits in number ', x, ' is ', str(sum_odd_n))
</pre>
```